# To get International Dvorak for Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, keyboard, dvorak, international

**How can you have International Dvorak for Snow Leopard?**

I need A with dots dot O with dots for Dvorak.

OS X has four types of Dvoraks, but none of them is Dvorak International like in Debian and many other Linux and BSD distros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using the standard English Dvorak, but can type accents quite easily. For dots over a letter (umlaut), type <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, then the letter you want. <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is `ç`, <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is for an `´` over the letter, <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> gives `^`, <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> gives `` ` ``, etc.

Comment: Yes, the keyboard with deadkeys is definitely the best option, since it is a lot more flexible with many languages than a single "international" keyboard. It is also faster to type with it, since you do not have remember the location of every special letter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a custom made dvorak variation called [ArkkuDvorak](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/kkuloves/dvorak.shtml#My_layout_with_other_languages) that I use. It's intended for Finnish but works relatively well for other Scandinavian languages as well.

Here is the [keylayout file for OS X](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/kkuloves/files/arkkudv.keylayout) that is installed by copying the file into `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/` on the system drive.

Comment: Cool — I didn't know anyone else at cs.helsinki was making their own keyboard layouts... If I ever bump into Arkku, we'll probably run into an argument about the merits of Dvorak.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to create your own keyboard layouts. The dmg contains *Dvorak.keylayout* and *DVORAK-QWERTYCMD.keylayout*, nothing like Dvorak International though.

I don't know about the one in Debian, but there isn't any standard international version of Dvorak AFAIK. The closest thing I found was [arjenvankol.com/dvorak.php](http://arjenvankol.com/dvorak.php), but it doesn't have a download for an OS X .keylayout.